# Action Bar --> Action Item background

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I was trying to change the background of the ActionItem Icons, when clicked android by default has a background. I tried to change it by overriding

`<style name="CustomActionBar" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo">

        <item name="android:selectableItemBackground">@null</item>
.......
</style>`.

But i was not able to make the default background highlight when clicked go away. I also noticed that the background for the overflow menu icon which appears on the Action bar (by default if you have overflow items) go away but not the actionitems appearing on the action bar. Am I missing something here?

Comment: What you're doing should work. I tested exactly what you posted. There has to be something else you're missing. Did you apply your theme in your Manifest?

Comment: Yes i did , not sure why its not working.

Comment: try here 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9019512/how-can-i-change-the-touch-effect-color-of-the-actionbar-in-android-3-0-and-high ,  also pay attention which device sdk you run you need to create seperate directory for devices with SDK 13  -  "values-v13"