# custom CAB background android

Tags: android, background, android-actionbar

Can the background for the CAB (contextual action bar) in android, be changed?
I am using it in my application, and when the application is installed on a tablet (3.0 - 3.2 API) the CAB has a yellow color and one look, and when the application is installed on phone with 4.0+ API it has some kind of blue background and another look. 
Can I do sth about this and have the same look everywhere?

note: my application is intended to run on 3.0+ api's

Comment: Can you please post your solution if you have found it?

Comment: Look in the source for the Google IO 2012 app, and also this link [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11085308/changing-the-background-drawable-of-the-searchview-widget]. Here you have an explanation of the customizations of the action bar, but you can get an idea for the CAB also. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do this by defining your own themes. Use one of the standard themes (in your case you can use Theme.Holo since you are targeting Honeycomb+) as a start point and customize (i.e., override) those pieces that you want to change. In your case you would customize just the style for the CAB.

The [Styles and Themes](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html) section of Android dev site introduces you to this in brief. Two additional places to look for real world example of how this has been done are:

1. [Actionbar Sherlock](http://actionbarsherlock.com/). Look at the actual library source (rather than the samples).
2. [Google IO 2012 app](http://code.google.com/p/iosched/source/checkout).

Comment: I will check the links out. Thank u!