# Change SearchView back Icon color

Tags: android, android-fragments

Is there a way to change the color of the arrow displayed on a SearchView when its expanded?
[image]

I have tried everything with no results.

Comment: See this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9252354/how-to-customize-the-back-button-on-actionbar

Comment: This worked for me
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44904085/how-to-set-the-toolbar-collapseicon-color-programmatically

Answer (score 21, accepted):

To change Back Icon color add below attribute in your `android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar` Toolbar

```
app:collapseIcon="@drawable/back_arrow"
```

Also to change close button icon add the following piece of code

```
ImageView searchClose = searchView.findViewById(android.support.v7.appcompat.R.id.search_close_btn);
searchClose.setImageResource(R.drawable.close);
```

Comment: Short, Clear and Working Answer like a Boss!

Comment: `searchClose` is actually the button to remove the current search, not the collapse button.

Answer (score 1):

See Abdul Rahman's answer here ([Styling a SearchView in Android Action Bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11527636/styling-a-searchview-in-android-action-bar))

```
@Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
    {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu);
        restoreActionBar();

        SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
        MenuItem searchMenuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
        SearchView searchView = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(searchMenuItem);
        searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));

        SearchView.SearchAutoComplete searchAutoComplete = (SearchView.SearchAutoComplete)searchView.findViewById(android.support.v7.appcompat.R.id.search_src_text);
        searchAutoComplete.setHintTextColor(Color.WHITE);
        searchAutoComplete.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);

        View searchplate = (View)searchView.findViewById(android.support.v7.appcompat.R.id.search_plate);
        searchplate.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.texfield_searchview_holo_light);

        ImageView searchCloseIcon = (ImageView)searchView.findViewById(android.support.v7.appcompat.R.id.search_close_btn);
        searchCloseIcon.setImageResource(R.drawable.clear_search);

        ImageView voiceIcon = (ImageView)searchView.findViewById(android.support.v7.appcompat.R.id.search_voice_btn);
        voiceIcon.setImageResource(R.drawable.abc_ic_voice_search);

        ImageView searchIcon = (ImageView)searchView.findViewById(android.support.v7.appcompat.R.id.search_mag_icon);
        searchIcon.setImageResource(R.drawable.abc_ic_search);


        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another approach:

```
<style name="ActivityTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault.Light">
    <item name="android:actionBarTheme">@style/searchActionBarTheme</item>
</style>

<style name="searchActionBarTheme" parent="@android:style/ThemeOverlay.Material.Dark.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/back_key_color</item> <!-- back key color defined here!! -->
    <item name="android:actionBarWidgetTheme">@style/searchViewTheme</item>
</style>

<style name="searchViewTheme" parent="@android:style/ThemeOverlay.Material.Light">
    <item name="android:editTextColor">@color/edit_text_color</item>
    <item name="android:colorControlActivated">@color/search_cursor_color</item>
</style>
```

Use ActivityTheme for your Activity in Manifest.xml

Answer (score 0):

**Change SearchView close Icon color**

```
SearchView  searchView = (SearchView) findViewById(R.id.searchView1);

    ImageView searchClose  = (ImageView) searchView.findViewById(search.getContext().getResources().getIdentifier("android:id/search_close_btn", null, null));

    searchClose.setColorFilter (R.color.black);
```

Answer (score -1):

I am using SearchView in Toolbar, and I could change the color using Reflection.

```
try {
    final Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    Field mCollapseIcon = toolbar.getClass().getDeclaredField("mCollapseIcon");
    mCollapseIcon.setAccessible(true);
    Drawable drw = (Drawable) mCollapseIcon.get(toolbar);
    drw.setTint(color);
}
catch (Exception e) {
}
```