# How to remove the Android SearchView left space?

Tags: android, android-appcompat, searchview, android-4.4-kitkat

I'm trying to remove the left space before the search view of Android, without success. I tried every answer I found on Internet but didn't work.
I'm using AppCompat themes for this activity. I'm targeting KitKat api (19).

Can someone help me please?
[image]

**EDIT**

Layout of activity

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/MainLayout"
android:background="#6ED19E">
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/BackgroundLayout"
    android:background="#6ED19E">
    <ImageView
        android:src="@drawable/bgpattern"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/PatternImageView"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop" />
    <TextView
        android:text="Já estamos em muitas cidades\nEstamos na sua?"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/ManyCityLabel"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="25dp"
        android:width="20dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textStyle="normal" />
</RelativeLayout>
<ListView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/LocationsListView"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    android:visibility="invisible" />
```

Menu

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content">
  <item android:id="@+id/LocationSearch"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        tools:showAsAction="always"
        tools:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"/>
</menu>
```

The iconified  stuff I did programatically because when I change the xml didn't work

**EDIT** 
If I set the background color of SearchView

[image]

The search doesn't fit the entire space.
Why?

Comment: post your xml file

Comment: @KingofMasses done

Comment: Try setting the background behind the Search View to a bright color to make sure the search bar is expanding fully in parent view.

Comment: native Search bar itself has a fixed size beyond that it cant expand its not the non removable space that creates it its like a layout to the right with fixed width

Comment: "The iconified stuff I did programatically because when I change the xml didn't work" - Can you please post related code (ie onCreate)?

Comment: @GIBINTHOMAS So he should put a dummy view to the right of Search View with sufficient with to take up remaining space? (simple <view/> could be used for this).

Comment: Sure it works?I haven't tried but i think the menu item still will be it na?

Comment: @LeandroDeMelloFagundes Why are you choosing not to show title in that remaining space on left? It kinda looks weird without title.

Comment: @BhalchandraSW it's just a gateway screen. I really don't need the title there

Comment: @BhalchandraSW A title goes there huh. Well that's the problem...

Comment: @BhalchandraSW can't I have an activity without title?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11527636/styling-a-searchview-in-android-action-bar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: Get output like this:]

You can do following:

Hide app bar in `onCreate()` like so:

```
// Hide UI first
ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
if (actionBar != null) {
    actionBar.hide();
}
```

In the layout file set background to green (or your colour), add a `SearchView` and set background for `SearchView` to white like so:

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
    ...
    android:background="#00FF00"
    ...>

    <android.support.v7.widget.SearchView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#FFF" />
    ...
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    ....
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

I am pretty sure that your other search interface code shall work. You only need to redirect your event calls.

Comment: Could try adding **`<activity android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" />`** to manifest.

Comment: It doesn't make sense to mee. I'm not talking about your answer, but the way we do the things. I already developed it to the IOS plataform and was so easy. Now, I'll have to code my own search bar because android can't let me to fill the bar with my seach? weird :(

Comment: After thinking a lot and spending soo much time with this, I give up and accepted your answer! Thanks @BhalchandraSW

Answer (score 1):

make a custom search bar in the activity layout and set its height and width according to you

Comment: BhalchandraSW provided a nice example of this... I'll give ya kudos for the succinct and pertinent suggestion though, b/c your are right (either do this or modify the builtin SearchView http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11527636/styling-a-searchview-in-android-action-bar)?

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content">
  <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/FullWidthSearchBar"
    android:background="#DD2277"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <item android:id="@+id/LocationSearch"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        tools:showAsAction="always"
        tools:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"/>
     <view android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
  </LinearLayout>
</menu>
```

Answer (score 0):

> 1. Get a reference/handle to the SearchView
> 2. Then a ref to the Title's view with getChildAt (need to experiment, start at 0)
> 3. Set TextView's visibility to gone.

```
View sv = findViewById(R.Id.SearchView);
View tv = sv.getChildAt(n);
tv.setVisibility(GONE);
```