# Sherlock action bar change text color

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

I am using sherlock action bar Version 4.1.0 *(2012-05-17)*.
How can I change the color of the text color in this screenshot ? On the actual device it is barelly readable

[image]

i have this theme

```
<style name="MyTheme" parent="@style/Theme.Sherlock.Light">
    <item name="android:textSize">20dp</item> 
</style>
```

And this in AndroidManifest.xml

```
<application
        android:name="abc.MyApp"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:logo="@drawable/logo"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/MyTheme" 
        >
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

thanks to this [Answer To: Changing the background drawable of the searchview widget](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11669808/579646)

```
SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) a.getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
SearchView searchView = new android.widget.SearchView(a.getApplicationContext());
int searchPlateId = searchView.getContext().getResources().getIdentifier("android:id/search_src_text", null, null);
// Getting the 'search_plate' LinearLayout.
AutoCompleteTextView searchPlate = (AutoCompleteTextView) searchView.findViewById(searchPlateId);
// Setting background of 'search_plate' to earlier defined drawable.
searchPlate.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
...
```

Answer (score 3):

Actually i've managed to style the SearchView text color in abs 4.2 by doing the following:

```
<style name="MyTheme" parent="Theme.Sherlock.Light">

    <item name="searchAutoCompleteTextView">@style/Widget.Styled.SearchAutocompleteTextView</item>

    <item name="queryHint">@string/Search</item>
    <item name="android:queryHint">@string/Search</item>


</style>

<style name="Widget.Styled.SearchAutocompleteTextView" parent="Widget.Sherlock.Light.SearchAutoCompleteTextView">
    <item name="android:textColor">YOU_COLOR_HERE</item>

</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't have any experience with Sherlock, but did you try adding:

```
<item name="android:textColor">@color/my_color</item>
```

to the Sherlock action bar theme?

And then in your values/color.xml you have the color:

```
<color name="my_color">#ff00ff00</color>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this one, it's right. :D

```
AutoCompleteTextView searchText = (AutoCompleteTextView) searchView.findViewById(R.id.abs__search_src_text);
searchText.setHintTextColor(getResources().getColor(color.black));
searchText.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(color.black));
```