# Search View Change Search Menu Item image

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, searchview

When using the theme Theme.Sherlock.Light

[image: weird icon]

and using a searchable.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<searchable xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:hint="@string/location_search_hint"
    android:icon="@drawable/action_search"
 >

</searchable>
```

I expect the Search icon to take my own @drawable/action_search which is white but it's ignoring it and it takes the one from the light theme.

How would I be able to change that?

Comment: Would be interesting to know. Have you found a solution for that?

Comment: Nop not yet, I think it's an android bug : http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=21774&can=5&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars   and there's maybe a solution but I haven't tried it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11085308/changing-the-background-drawable-of-the-searchview-widget

Comment: So what happens if you try the solution below? Any error message? Exceptions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note the menu needs to have the collapseActionView attribute

```
android:showAsAction="ifRoom|collapseActionView"
```

[Source](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ActionBarSherlock/issues/823)

EDIT:

Actually I found a better solution
the Menu can keep the following line:

```
android:showAsAction="ifRoom"
```

And the icon for the search need to use the same name as the one from ActionBarSherlock/AppCompat/Native

for app compat it would be abc_ic_menu_share_holo_dark.png

Answer (score 1):

So well, I think I found a solution for your problem.
Add this line to your themes.xml

```
<item name="searchViewSearchIcon">@drawable/menu_search</item>
```

There you can "overwrite" the styles like the magnifier icon with your own drawables.

You may also use the other styles like

```
<item name="searchViewCloseIcon">@drawable/menu_search_close</item>
```

etc.

Hope this helps,
 Tobias