# apply Orange style to my search view

Tags: android

I want to apply Orange style to my search view which is an item in the action bar menu , I generated the orange style using  http://android-holo-colors.com/ and I assigned the style to my search view using

```
 <item
        android:id="@+id/menu_search"
        style="@style/EditTextOrange"
        android:actionViewClass="android.widget.SearchView"
        android:icon="@drawable/action_search"
        android:showAsAction="always"
        android:title="search"/>
```

my style

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<!-- Generated with http://android-holo-colors.com -->
<resources xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

  <style name="EditTextOrange" parent="android:Widget.EditText">
      <item name="android:background">@drawable/edit_text_holo_light</item>
      <item name="android:textColor">#000000</item>
  </style>

</resources>
```

How can I apply the style to my search view ?

Answer (score 1):

You can change the SearchView drawable like this:

```
<style name="EditTextOrange" parent="android:Theme.Holo">

    <item name="android:searchViewTextField">@drawable/mySearchView</item>

</style>
```

Comment: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:searchViewTextField'.

Comment: What API are you building against. This will only work for Android HC+ (of course).

Comment: For ActionBarSherlock it should be <item name="searchViewTextField">

Comment: @DoctororDrive yap, and also you would  have to inherit your styles from the Sherlock Theme.

Comment: I read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11085308/changing-the-background-drawable-of-the-searchview-widget and it  didn't work for me

Answer (score 1):

I solve the problem using textfield_activated_holo_light image which is generated from  http://android-holo-colors.com/

```
searchPlate.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.textfield_activated_holo_light);
```

Comment: Hey @Mohammed, the only issue is that the Holo drawable which just looks like an underline seems to be positioned further away from the bottom of the `ActionBar` then the default Holo underline?  Why is that?