# Android: SearchView

Tags: android

this is what I have in xml file

```
    <SearchView
        android:id="@+id/searchView1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:iconifiedByDefault="false">
    </SearchView>
```

This is how its looks on device

[image]

But I want this think to look like this:

[image]

How to do that ? Is that possible with searchView or I should use EditText with image inside ?

P.S: Searchview is not in action bar

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/index.html . Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

I think you have to change the background of your **android:id="@+id/search_plate"**

[Changing the background drawable of the searchview widget](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11085308/changing-the-background-drawable-of-the-searchview-widget)

Answer (score 0):

This behaviour is changed by the setIconifiedByDefault method (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SearchView.html#setIconifiedByDefault(boolean)). If you call the method when setting up the SearchView, like below, the icon will be **outside** the TextView:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getSupportMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.mymenu, menu);

    SearchView searchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.search).getActionView();
    // ...
    searchView.setIconifiedByDefault(false); // the icon will be outside the search view
}
```

So, to get the desired behaviour, just don't call setIconifiedByDefault (which is, according to the docs, the same as calling it with a true parameter)