# How to put overlay View over action bar Sherlock

Tags: android, overlay, actionbarsherlock, menuitem

I want to set some view over action bar that will display Tutorial text (Like click here and send email...). Is this possible? I ask because i know that action bar uses the top space on layout, and a fragment or activity uses remaining space.

My second question is how to display all action items on action bar. I use ActionBarSherlock library and i see that i have room for one more action item, but it's not displaying on action bar. I set in xml ifRoom option on item...

Thanks!!!

Comment: I'd suggest that you ask second question as separate posting (and remove it from this one) because it's not directly related to the issue stated in subject.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

There are multiple ways to achieve a tutorial-like overlay. Probably the easiest one is to use specially prepared [Dialog](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html) window with transparent background and without dim behind.

### Using custom `Dialog` for tutorial overlay

First of all we have to prepare content for the `Dialog`. In this example there will be one `TextView` inside `RelativeLayout` which is the most useful layout here.

Content of `info_overlay.xml` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
        android:padding="3dp"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Now, we can use this layout to create our `Dialog`:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Dialog overlayInfo = new Dialog(MainActivity.this);
        // Making sure there's no title.
        overlayInfo.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        // Making dialog content transparent.
        overlayInfo.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(
                new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
        // Removing window dim normally visible when dialog are shown.
        overlayInfo.getWindow().clearFlags(
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DIM_BEHIND);
        // Setting position of content, relative to window.
        WindowManager.LayoutParams params = overlayInfo.getWindow().getAttributes();
        params.gravity = Gravity.TOP | Gravity.LEFT;
        params.x = 100;
        params.y = 20;
        // If user taps anywhere on the screen, dialog will be cancelled.
        overlayInfo.setCancelable(true);
        // Setting the content using prepared XML layout file.
        overlayInfo.setContentView(R.layout.info_overlay);
        overlayInfo.show();
    }
```

#### Result

Below is the screenshot of the above solution working. Note the `TextView` over `ActionBar`.

[image]

#### A few notes about solution

- If you'll have a dedicated button to dismiss tutorial you can probably use `setCancelable(false)` to avoid accidental closing of tutorial.
- This solution works with any theme with any action bar solution (either OS-provided, *Android Support Library* or *ActionBar Sherlock*)

### Other solutions/helpers

Take a look at [Showcase View library](https://github.com/Espiandev/ShowcaseView) as it focuses on creating tutorial-like screens in easy way. I'm not sure however that it can easily overlay actionbars.

Comment: I just saw it..i will test it tomorrow, but i think that this is the right thing!!! Thanks for comprehensive response about my question.

Comment: @Jovan Hope it helps. Please move your second question about visibility of items in actionbar to separate posting. It'll for sure get more attention from SO users.

Comment: works with normal ActionBar too and allows to do full screen overlay.