# Display an ImageView above the ActionBar

Tags: android, imageview, android-actionbar, overlay

I want to know, how Google does this. 
I read much articles, but none of the given solutions works for me.

I dont want the Actionbar to be Transparent. I dont want to Hide the Actionbar. I dont want to Overlay the Actionbar with an ImageView like this:

https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B0T-2P7o0EFsMGF1Y2s5RjdjdUk/edit
https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B0T-2P7o0EFsQXQ3bU1kT1VPQ1E/edit

As you see in the background, the Actionbar layout isnt moved upwards, so i guess that the ActionBar is still behind the Image.

Comment: Interesting question. [The contacts app is open source](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Contacts/+/master), so you could go through the source code, if you want to know that.

Answer (score 0):

You should have no problem covering the action bar using a [dialog](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html), that's part of the reason why they exist.

There's a similar answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15618537/how-to-put-overlay-view-over-action-bar-sherlock) with an example.