# Customizing SearchView Programmatically

Tags: android, android-edittext, ime, searchview

I want to customize the 'edittext' of the Search View widget in my application.I want to programmatically set its background drawable. I also want to programmatically add the flag     `android:imeOptions="flagNoExtractUi"` so that on land scape mode, soft keyboard will only cover half the screen.

Anyone know how I can make this customizations on the search views 'edittext'?

[image: The search view]

Comment: check this out http://stackoverflow.com/a/11669808/1932105

Comment: Thanks Ahmed, How would I programatically set the imeoptions `android:imeOptions="flagNoExtractUi"` once I have the view?

Comment: try. youView.setImeOptions(flagNoExtractUi);

Answer (score 1):

This is what I did. I studied `abs_search_view.xml` in action bar sherlock library and learnt that `R.id.search_plate` represents a LinearLayour. The first child of the LinearLayout is a view whose class is `com.actionbarsherlock.widget.SearchView$SearchAutoComplete`. So I retrieved the first child and cast it to `com.actionbarsherlock.widget.SearchView.SearchAutoComplete`, did a null check and later set the ime options with `searchText.setImeOptions(EditorInfo.IME_FLAG_NO_EXTRACT_UI)` as adviced by Ahmend in the comments. Hope this helps someone.

```
public static void styleSearchView(SearchView searchView, Context context) {
    LinearLayout searchPlate = (LinearLayout) searchView
            .findViewById(R.id.abs__search_plate);
    // TODO
    // searchPlate.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.your_custom_drawable);
    if (searchPlate != null)
        ((com.actionbarsherlock.widget.SearchView.SearchAutoComplete) searchPlate
                .getChildAt(0))
                .setImeOptions(EditorInfo.IME_FLAG_NO_EXTRACT_UI);
    AutoCompleteTextView searchText = (AutoCompleteTextView) searchView
            .findViewById(R.id.abs__search_src_text);
    if (searchText != null)
        searchText.setImeOptions(EditorInfo.IME_FLAG_NO_EXTRACT_UI);
    // TODO
    // searchText.setHintTextColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.your_custom_color));
}
```

[image]