# change x mark icon in searchview

Tags: android, searchview

I have a searchview below action bar .I tried replacing the x mark(close icon) with another drawable .I tried the code below and i am getting this error:
**error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'searchViewCloseIcon'.**

please let me know how to resolve this error .I really appreciate any help .Thanks in advance.

in styles.xml in values folder

```
<style name="Theme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
<item name="android:searchViewCloseIcon">@android:drawable/ic_search_close</item>
</style>
```

Comment: Where your drawable icon resides ? Is it in your drawable folder ?

Comment: yes its in drawable folder

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try out as below:

```
 <item name="android:searchViewCloseIcon">@drawable/ic_search_close</item>
```

Answer (score 4):

I won't go into too much detail because there's an excellent post here: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11085308/changing-the-background-drawable-of-the-searchview-widget?answertab=votes#tab-top) in regards to adapting the searchview and why the above answers will not work.

If you would like to change your 'X', the following works to change the color

```
   int crossId = searchView.getContext().getResources().getIdentifier("android:id/search_close_btn", null, null);            // Getting the 'search_plate' LinearLayout.
    ImageView image = (ImageView) searchView.findViewById(crossId);
    Drawable d = image.getDrawable();
    d.setColorFilter(Color.WHITE, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
```

If you would like to change the icon

```
   int crossId = searchView.getContext().getResources().getIdentifier("android:id/search_close_btn", null, null);            // Getting the 'search_plate' LinearLayout.
    ImageView image = (ImageView) searchView.findViewById(crossId);
    image.setImageResource(R.drawable.NEW_ICON_HERE);
```

Comment: I spent an unholy amount of time to make it work and this seems to work. I'm just wondering why Android has to make literally everything so frikkin hard....

Answer (score 0):

```
Try this
    <style name="srcclose">   
    <item name="android:searchViewCloseIcon">@drawable/ic_search_close</item>
    </style>
```

Comment: pasted in styles.xml - getting an error : error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 
 'android:searchViewCloseIcon'.