# Search view border color change and search hint icon change

Tags: android, searchview, android-search

How to change the Android searchview border color and searchview hint icon?

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [Changing the background drawable of the searchview widget](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11085308/changing-the-background-drawable-of-the-searchview-widget)

Answer (score 2):

You have to use reflection to style the SearchView. Check out: http://novoda.com/blog/styling-actionbar-searchview

Comment: the link is not accessible.

Answer (score 0):

```
MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.options_menu, menu);

    // Get the SearchView and set the searchable configuration
    SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
    SearchView searchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.menu_search).getActionView();
    // Assumes current activity is the searchable activity
   AutoCompleteTextView searchText = (AutoCompleteTextView)searchView.findViewById(R.id.abs__search_src_text);
    searchText.setHintTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
   searchText.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
    searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));
    searchView.setIconifiedByDefault(false);
```