# Customizing Android's Search View "line"

Tags: android, android-actionbar, searchview

Currently, I have in my project a SearchView that looks like this:
[image: how I don't want the search]

Eye-burning, ain't it? So I need it to look like this:

[image: how I want the search]

Can this be done?

I don't even know what that line's called, so I'm not really sure how I'd go looking for it, which admittedly might be part of why I can't seem to find the answer, but I have tried messing with EditText properties and it didn't seem to work.

Not using appcompat, application is Android 4.0+ only.

So far I've tried to look for set options on the searchView documentation (no luck) and setting the following under ActionBar in styles.xml:

```
    <item name="android:editTextBackground">@color/white_color_is_white</item>
```

Comment: question: what have you tried so far ... are you using appcompatv7?

Comment: Updated the question with the information.

Comment: seems like new material api will fix it (tint(new attr for views)? corect words? my native is not english)  http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2014/10/appcompat-v21-material-design-for-pre.html one of the headers is about "Widget tinting"

Comment: another solution is: take a look at android source, take drawable for editbox/searchview editbox_or_searchview_state_background.xml(not sure about name but somthing similar), take the 9-patch pngs from this xml and copy to your project then modify ... and then set android:background of EditBox/SearchView to this drawable(xml)

Comment: simple googling returns that what i was trying to say in prev comment someone already did http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11085308/changing-the-background-drawable-of-the-searchview-widget