# Android - Button set on TouchDown Color

Tags: java, android, button

I have a button and typically when I click it this light blue color comes up around the button to show that you are touching down on it. How can I change this color?

I also want to change the default background color of this button which I do programmatically like this:

```
button.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
```

And when I do this I know it won't change the touchdown color which is what I am trying to do, but it makes the light blue color on touchdown go away which confuses me?

But my question is how to I change the touch down color?

I talking about this

This is not being pressed down just normal:

[image]

This is as I hold the button down

[image]

Thanks for the help!! :)

Answer (score 0):

Button backgrounds have states. To use a custom background, you have to define a selector xml file.

See [Buttons#CustomBackground](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/button.html#CustomBackground)

Comment: You would still have define a selector if you want your button to have different states. You can swap the selector at runtime by calling `button.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.selector);`

Comment: okay when I add the xml file in the example you posted I get cannot resolve `@drawable/button_pressed`

Comment: You have to create it, that's what makes it custom. Here is a very similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11085308/changing-the-background-drawable-of-the-searchview-widget

Comment: You can take a look at the android sdk's button resources: `sdk\platforms\android-xx\data\res\drawable-mdpi` btn_default_disabled, btn_default_focused, btn_default_pressed