# How to align magnifier icon in SearchView precisely?

Tags: android, user-interface, customization, searchview

I want to customize the default Android `SearchView` to make it look like this:
[image]

I could use reflection for accessing to propeties of `SearchView` and use ImageSpan to add the magnifier icon before "Search" (the hint text) then set it as hint text for `SearchView`'s EditText.

But I also need the magnifier to be align in the SearchView with exact pixel values as illustrated in the image above. I haven't figure out any way to achieve this yet.

How can I implement it?

Comment: Take a look to this: [vArDo answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11669808/1636209)

Comment: @phemt.latd: Thanks for you comment. I read that answer but haven't found what I wanted.