# Styling SearchView Android

Tags: android, android-styles, searchview, android-search

Hello i'm overriding SearchView attributes with values from the LightTheme:

```
<style name="LightSearchView" parent="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen">
 <!-- SearchView attributes -->
    <item name="android:searchDropdownBackground">@android:drawable/search_dropdown_light</item>
    <item name="android:searchViewTextField">@drawable/textfield_searchview_holo_light</item>
    <item name="android:searchViewTextFieldRight">@drawable/textfield_searchview_right_holo_light</item>
    <item name="android:searchViewCloseIcon">@android:drawable/ic_clear_holo_light</item>
    <item name="android:searchViewSearchIcon">@android:drawable/ic_search_api_holo_light</item>
    <item name="android:searchViewGoIcon">@android:drawable/ic_go_search_api_holo_light</item>
    <item name="android:searchViewVoiceIcon">@android:drawable/ic_voice_search_api_holo_light</item>
    <item name="android:searchViewEditQuery">@android:drawable/ic_commit_search_api_holo_light</item>
</style>
```

But the error:
    res\values\styles.xml:26: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:searchDropdownBackground'

Appears for all the items.

How do I override then (for API 13+).

Also, it's a notice that on appcompat-v21 they exposed those fields to be overrideable, but I did downloaded appcompat src and added as a Android Library Project but overriding the values dont change the SearchView.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Changing the background drawable of the searchview widget](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11085308/changing-the-background-drawable-of-the-searchview-widget)

Answer (score 0):

You can´t set `android:searchDropdownBackground` and other field style using the theme `NoTitleBar` or any other themes

read this:
[Changing the background drawable of the searchview widget](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11085308/changing-the-background-drawable-of-the-searchview-widget)