# How to remove white underline in a SearchView widget in Toolbar Android

Tags: android, searchview, android-toolbar, android-search

I am using the Toolbar search widget in my project. Everything works fine but expect the thing which I am completely stuck up with removing the underline below the search field in my toolbar. I have tried many solutions and nothing works out. Below are some of the solutions that I tried.

**Requirement is to remove white underline in the image**

[image]

**Ist Solution:**

```
//Removing underline

    int searchPlateId = searchView.getContext().getResources().getIdentifier("android:id/search_plate", null, null);
    View searchPlate = searchView.findViewById(searchPlateId);
    if (searchPlate!=null) {
        searchPlate.setBackgroundColor (Color.TRANSPARENT);
        int searchTextId = searchPlate.getContext ().getResources ().getIdentifier ("android:id/search_src_text", null, null);

    }
```

**IInd Solution:**

```
 EditText searchEdit = ((EditText)searchView.findViewById(android.support.v7.appcompat.R.id.search_src_text));
 searchEdit.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
```

The above code works to change the background of EditText but still underline is displaying below the close icon in SearchBar.

**Complete code that I am using for SearchBar widget as follows:**

```
    @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater infl) {
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, infl);
        MenuInflater inflater = getActivity().getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.action_search, menu);
        final SearchView searchView = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat
                .getActionView(menu.findItem(R.id.search));

        SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getActivity ().getSystemService (getActivity ().SEARCH_SERVICE);
        searchView.setSearchableInfo (searchManager.getSearchableInfo (getActivity ().getComponentName ()));

        //changing edittext color
        EditText searchEdit = ((EditText)searchView.findViewById(android.support.v7.appcompat.R.id.search_src_text));
        searchEdit.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
}
```

**action_search.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:compat="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item android:id="@+id/search"
        android:title="Search"
        android:icon="@drawable/abc_ic_search_api_mtrl_alpha"
        compat:showAsAction="ifRoom|collapseActionView"
        compat:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView" />
</menu>
```

possible duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11085308/changing-the-background-drawable-of-the-searchview-widget/11669808#11669808)

Comment: try to set this two properties in xml file android:submitBackground="@android:color/transparent"
android:queryBackground="@android:color/transparent"

Comment: Does the thin line render automatically for you ? I am struggling to add a line !

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Once try as follows

```
View v = searchView.findViewById(android.support.v7.appcompat.R.id.search_plate);
v.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("here give actionbar color code"));
```

Hope this will helps you.

Comment: what do you do when the searchView has an Voice button ? i've tried to use the same trick with the `search_voice_btn` id but it's not works

Comment: Thanks a lot. In my case I set the Background drawable to null i.e. _searchView.findViewById(android.support.v7.appcompat.R.id.search_plate)setBackground(null)_

Comment: Not help me.Underline is stay any way

Comment: The following answer should be the accepted answer instead of this.

Comment: For AndroidX use: androidx.appcompat.R.id.search_plate

Answer (score 171):

If you are using SearchView then use for API below 21

```
android:queryBackground="@android:color/transparent"
```

you can use below code if you are using API 21 or more

```
app:queryBackground="@android:color/transparent"
```

Comment: FYI, this property is available from Api Level 21 onwards.

Comment: try app:queryBackground="@android:color/transparent"  =)

Comment: app:queryBackground="@android:color/transparent" works properly on Api Level 21 instead of  android:queryBackground="@android:color/transparent"

Comment: It doesn't work for me on API 29 :( I still see the underline.

Comment: TBH, it is **NOT API LEVEL** that makes decision, it is **the VIEW type you use**. For example, I use `SearchView` (not `androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView` ) in API 28, then I should use `android:` prefix instead.

Answer (score 57):

**Just add this line if you  are using a v7 or androidx widget**

```
app:queryBackground="@android:color/transparent"
```

Comment: If 'app:' doesn't work try 'android:'. It worked for me.

Answer (score 43):

Or you can do this through styles:

```
<style name="SearchViewMy" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Light.SearchView">
    <item name="submitBackground">@color/primaryColor</item>
    <item name="queryBackground">@color/primaryColor</item>
</style>
```

*queryBackground* is attribute for the query background. If you support voice search you may want to remove the line also under that mic button. Thats what *submitBackground* attribute is for.

Then of course apply the style to your theme.

```
<style name="Theme.App" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar.FullScreen">
    <item name="searchViewStyle">@style/SearchViewMy</item>
</style>
```

Comment: This is the best answer as it doesn't make assumptions about the view hierarchy implementation of the support library, which may change without notice.

Comment: Indeed a best answer! Prefer this first before trying any other solution.

Comment: Nope. Does not work

Answer (score 12):

For AndroidX I used this based on other answers here,

```
searchView.findViewById(androidx.appcompat.R.id.search_plate)
        .setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT)
```

Comment: Awesome solution Thanks:)

Answer (score 7):

if you want to remove the underline from SearchView, then just copy paste the below code to your SearchView. it works

```
 android:queryBackground="@null"
```

like this,

```
      <SearchView
                android:id="@+id/searchView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:queryBackground="@null"
                />
```

Answer (score 6):

You can try using the below code, works like a charm for me.

```
View v = searchView.findViewById(android.support.v7.appcompat.R.id.search_plate);
    v.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context,android.R.color.transparent));
```

Comment: Instead of `ContextCompat.getColor...` simply use `Color.TRANSPARENT`.

Answer (score 3):

The below piece of code works for me.

```js
val searchView = menu?.findItem(R.id.action_search)?.actionView as SearchView
searchView.findViewById<View>(androidx.appcompat.R.id.search_plate).background = null
```

Answer (score 2):

For **androidx** and **kotlin**:

```
        menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.conversation_list_screen_menu, menu)
        val searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search)
        searchView = searchItem.actionView as SearchView
        searchView?.findViewById<View>(androidx.appcompat.R.id.search_plate)?.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT)
```

Answer (score 0):

The code for changing the background color of SearchView edit text is below

```
public static void setSearchViewEditTextBackgroundColor(Context context, SearchView searchView, int backgroundColor){
    int searchPlateId = context.getResources().getIdentifier("android:id/search_plate", null, null);
    ViewGroup viewGroup = (ViewGroup) searchView.findViewById(searchPlateId);
    viewGroup.setBackgroundColor(ComponentUtils.getColor(context, backgroundColor));
}
```

If your action bar background color is white then call the above method as follow.

```
setSearchViewEditTextBackgroundColor(this, searchView, R.color.white);
```

Now the underline from SearchView edit text will disappear.

Comment: Actually, this is the only answer that worked for me. An expanded explanation on why this works is available [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11085308/changing-the-background-drawable-of-the-searchview-widget/11669808#11669808)

Answer (score 0):

First you should get the bottom line simply like this:

```
searchPlate = (View) findViewById(R.id.search_plate);
```

Then you should set background color to transparent like this:

```
searchPlate.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
```

This works perfectly for androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView!