# Android SearchView icon disappears when SearchView style is overridden

Tags: android, searchview, android-styles

I have a SearchView in the main content area of my activity.

I need to override the SearchView style in my **style.xml** files (so I can remove the SearchView's underline - [as shown here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30842921/how-to-remove-white-underline-in-a-searchview-widget-in-toolbar-android)).

However, when I override the `SearchView` style, its `searchIcon` just disappears from the UI:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="searchViewStyle">@style/MySearchView</item>
    <item name="android:searchViewStyle">@style/MySearchView</item>
</style>

<style name="MySearchView" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Light.SearchView">
    <!-- nothing entered here yet! -->
</style>
```

I know I can specify my own drawable for the `searchIcon`, but I would like to use the default one.

So how do I specify `MySearchView` style without losing the default `searchIcon`?

**Update #1**

I don't know if this is normal, but I also have a problem where if I override the Button style using [this approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2410938/1617737), then my buttons lose all their padding and therefore become too small:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="buttonStyle">@style/MyButton</item>
    <item name="android:buttonStyle">@style/MyButton</item>
</style>

<style name="MyButton" parent="android:style/Widget.Button">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/white</item>
    <item name="android:background">@color/red</item>
</style>
```

Comment: You sure it's not just blending in with the background?

Comment: Yes, well, pretty sure. I've tried making the parent `Widget.AppCompat.Light.SearchView` and then `Widget.AppCompat.SearchView`. I've also temporarily given my activity a red background (rather than white) and there is still no sign of the searchIcon.

Comment: Hmm, not sure then. I couldn't reproduce the issue. Have you tried just specifying the default icon in your style, see what happens? It's `@drawable/abc_ic_search_api_material` (might be `abc_ic_search_api_mtrl_alpha`, depending on your support library version).

Comment: I can specify an icon with `<item name="android:searchIcon">@drawable/ic_search_black_24dp</item>`, but I'd like to get to the bottom of this issue. NB - The "do search" button has gone, too. See **Update #1** in my question as it seems all parent styles are lost for other views that I override.

Comment: Well, the `Button` issue is probably because you've set a color as the `background`. `Button`s use a specific background drawable to get their default look, and if you're wrapping the width/height, when that drawable's gone, there's nothing to wrap to but the text. You are using the appcompat `SearchView`, yeah?

Comment: "You are using the appcompat SearchView, yeah?"... "No." :-/ Sorted now - thank you. Do you want to post that as an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the issue here was using a framework class with a style meant for a support class. The correct `SearchView` class to use with an `AppCompat` theme is `android.support.v7.widget.SearchView`, rather than `android.widget.SearchView`.

A framework `View` isn't going to be looking for attributes defined for a support `View`, so those attributes' settings will just be lost. Since no valid resources would be found during the `SearchView`'s construction, null would be set as the image for each icon's `ImageButton`, which would explain why multiple icons seemed to have disappeared with this style.