# How to remove underline in searchview in xamarin android application?

Tags: android, xamarin.android

In my project I need to display a search view to search the items that are displayed below in list view. So for that i have followed the tutorial from https://abhiandroid.com/ui/searchview for searchview implementation. And also as per our requirement we need to set some orange background color to the searchview. I have done similar way. But the issue is inside the search view there is some default line coming as underline. Can anybody tell me how to remove that line in xamarin android.

Code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/background">
    <SearchView
        android:id="@+id/simpleSearchView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:iconifiedByDefault="false"
        android:queryHint="Search here"
        android:background="@color/calculate_grey"
        app:MvxBind="Query  SearchQuery;Visibility Visible(IsIncompleteSignupHasData)" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/search_text_count"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/searchBar"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_normal"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/margin_large"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/margin_large"
        android:textSize="@dimen/text_semimedium"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        app:MvxBind="Text FarmerCountText;Typeface StringToFont('Montserrat-Medium')" />
```

Thanks a lot in advance

Comment: Please post some of your xml code. Thanks.

Comment: What about [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30842921/how-to-remove-white-underline-in-a-searchview-widget-in-toolbar-android)?