# How to remove underline on searchview with drawable background

Tags: android, android-layout, searchview, underline

[Snapshot from emulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XHEx1.jpg)

How can i remove the underline as shown in the picture?
Setting it to transparent or changing background does not help.

Already tried these solutions: [How to remove white underline in a SearchView widget in Toolbar Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30842921/how-to-remove-white-underline-in-a-searchview-widget-in-toolbar-android)

Both changing style to actionbar-searchview and programmaticly. Problem with changing querybackground is  that it will ignore the drawable background i have already set.

```
    <SearchView
    android:id="@+id/searchViewBar"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/rounded_corner"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:queryHint=" "
    />
```

Comment: That seems like elevation, have you tried that?

Comment: Have not used any elevation. Added some to test and the see difference, and it was noticeably different than the line.

Comment: If you want to make characters which are searched colored, see my question and answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59628149/how-can-we-have-searched-characters-colored-when-we-use-searchview-in-recyclervi

Comment: Can you post a picture of the result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change search_edit_frame, search_plate and search_bar where you have declared this view.

```
    int searchFrameId = searchView.getContext().getResources().getIdentifier("android:id/search_edit_frame", null, null);
View searchFrame = searchView.findViewById(searchFrameId);
searchFrame.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.rounded_corner);

int searchPlateId = searchView.getContext().getResources().getIdentifier("android:id/search_plate", null, null);
View searchPlate = findViewById(searchPlateId);
searchPlate.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.rounded_corner);

int searchBarId = searchView.getContext().getResources().getIdentifier("android:id/search_bar", null, null);
View searchBar = findViewById(searchBarId);
searchBar.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.rounded_corner);
```

Comment: I only needed the lines for searchPlate! Thanks. No way to do this in XML?

Answer (score 1):

Try the following code:

```
View v = searchView.findViewById(android.support.v7.appcompat.R.id.search_plate);
v.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("here give actionbar color code"));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
int searchPlateId = searchView.getContext().getResources().getIdentifier("android:id/search_plate", null, null);
View searchPlate = findViewById(searchPlateId);
searchPlate.setBackgroundResource(0);
```

This removes any type of background from the search plate.

Answer (score 0):

This is how it worked for me

```
val searchPlate = searchView.findViewById<View>(androidx.appcompat.R.id.search_plate)
searchPlate.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.search_textfield_shape)
```