# How to remove underline in an Query Text of a SearchView in AppBarLayout Android

Tags: android, kotlin, searchview, android-appbarlayout

I'm using AppBarLayout search widget in my app. Everything works fine but I'm completely stuck up with removing the underline below search field in my AppBarLayout.

The following was nonsense code. It did not resolve...

```
findViewById<View>(R.id.search_plate).setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, android.R.color.white))
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
val v = searchView.findViewById(android.support.v7.appcompat.R.id.search_plate);
v.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("Colour code"));
```

hope this will help you

Comment: have you tried these [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30842921/how-to-remove-white-underline-in-a-searchview-widget-in-toolbar-android)

Answer (score 0):

My answer is late but i hope it helps anyone
use the next line to find the search_plate

```
findViewById<View>(androidx.appcompat.R.id.search_plate)
```

but make sure that you are using **androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView** in your xml and your activity otherwise you will get Null Exception

Answer (score 0):

try this in searchview in xml

API below 21

```
android:queryBackground="@android:color/transparent"
```

API 21 and above

```
app:queryBackground="@android:color/transparent"
```