# How to change the style of SearchView?

Tags: java, android, searchview

I have to implement a `SearchView` in my application.

The XML declaration is as follows:

```
<SearchView
     android:id="@+id/searchView"
     style="@style/SearchViewStyle"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="20dp"
     android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
     android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
     android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
     app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
     app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
     app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

The style is:

```
<style name="SearchViewStyle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.SearchView">
 <item name="android:searchIcon">@drawable/ico_search</item>
 <item name="android:queryBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
```

and finally in the activity:

```
SearchView mSearchView = findViewById(R.id.searchView);
mSearchView.setIconifiedByDefault(true);
mSearchView.setSubmitButtonEnabled(false);
mSearchView.setOnQueryTextListener(this);
mSearchView.setQueryHint("Search here");
```

I don't understand how to change the text color of the hint and the background of the "edittext" where I type the keywords used for the research.

**What did I just try?**

Add this line in the style.xml

```
<item name="android:textSize">18sp</item>
<item name="android:textColor">@color/white</item>
```

or add this in my activity

```
AutoCompleteTextView searchText = (AutoCompleteTextView) searchView.findViewById(R.id.abs__search_src_text);
searchText.setHintTextColor(getResources().getColor(color.black));
searchText.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(color.black));
```

Those solutions didn't work.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11085308/changing-the-background-drawable-of-the-searchview-widget

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can style your SearchView like this:

```
<style name="Theme.MyTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat">
   <item name="searchViewStyle">@style/MySearchViewStyle</item>
</style>
<style name="MySearchViewStyle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.SearchView">
   <!-- Background for the search query section (e.g. EditText) -->
   <item name="queryBackground">...</item>
   <!-- Background for the actions section (e.g. voice, submit) -->
   <item name="submitBackground">...</item>
   <!-- Close button icon -->
   <item name="closeIcon">...</item>
   <!-- Search button icon -->
   <item name="searchIcon">...</item>
   <!-- Go/commit button icon -->
   <item name="goIcon">...</item>
   <!-- Voice search button icon -->
   <item name="voiceIcon">...</item>
   <!-- Commit icon shown in the query suggestion row -->
   <item name="commitIcon">...</item>
   <!-- Layout for query suggestion rows -->
   <item name="suggestionRowLayout">...</item>
</style>
```

Here is details information https://philio.me/styling-the-searchview-with-appcompat-v21/

Answer (score 0):

you can use EditeText insted of searchBox with same property by using shape:

```
  <EditText
                      android:id="@+id/edt_search"
                      android:layout_width="match_parent"
                      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                      android:layout_weight="1"
                      android:background="@drawable/shape_rectangle_edittext"
                      android:drawableRight="@drawable/ic_search_gray"
                      android:ems="10"
                      android:hint="@string/search_box"
                      android:imeOptions="actionSearch"
                      android:inputType="text"
                      android:padding="@dimen/size10"
                      android:textColorHint="#444"
                      android:textSize="@dimen/size16"
                      />
```

and shape_rectangle_edittext.xml in drawable:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:shape="rectangle" android:padding="10dp">
    <solid android:color="#777"/>
    <corners
        android:bottomRightRadius="10dp"
        android:bottomLeftRadius="10dp"
        android:topLeftRadius="10dp"
        android:topRightRadius="10dp"/>
</shape>
```