# Change background color in Search View Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-drawable, searchview, android-selector

Hey I want to add background color in search view in android. But I am trying to add selector but it's not working. Also I tried this [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11669808/11560810) but it's not working

**Search.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView
        android:id="@+id/searchView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/search_edit_text_rounded_corner"
        android:theme="@style/SearchViewTheme"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:closeIcon="@drawable/ic_cancel"
        app:searchIcon="@drawable/ic_search" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**styles.xml**

```
<style name="SearchViewTheme" parent="Widget.AppCompat.SearchView">
        <item name="android:textColorHint">@color/hint</item>
        <item name="android:editTextColor">@color/grey</item>
        <item name="android:fontFamily">@font/source_sans_pro_light</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/text_size</item>
        <item name="queryHint">@string/edit_text_hint</item>
        <item name="iconifiedByDefault">false</item>
</style>
```

**search_edit_text_rounded_corner.xml**

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/search_edit_text_selected" android:state_selected="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/search_edit_text_selected" android:state_pressed="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/search_edit_text_default" />
</selector>
```

**search_edit_text_selected.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid android:color="@color/red" />
    <stroke
        android:width="1dp"
        android:color="@color/red" />
    <corners android:radius="4dp" />
</shape>
```

**search_edit_text_default.xml**

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid android:color="@color/off_white" />
    <stroke
        android:width="1dp"
        android:color="@color/cloudy" />
    <corners android:radius="4dp" />
</shape>
```

**Actual Output**

Scenario 1 :- This is working fine when unfocused

[image]

Scenario 2 :- When I tried to select it not changing the color

[image]

**Expected Output**

**Scenario 1** is fine. I want to fix in **Scenario 2** when user focus and look like this

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Add back ground tint it will change the background color

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView
android:backgroundTint=""/>
```

Comment: I tried this already it's not working.