# How can I change the touch affect color of Actions with ActionBarSherlock?

Tags: android, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock, android-theme

I have several actions all of which display properly. When I click the actions however, the color comes up as the default blueish color and it looks awful with my app. How can I change the 'selected' color of the Action?

This is basically a duplicate of [`this question`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9019512/how-can-i-change-the-touch-effect-color-of-the-actionbar-in-android-3-0-and-high), except that one doesn't deal with ActionBarSherlock.

**EDIT**

Using the accepted answer, I am getting this error after adjusting `style.xml`

The error is `error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches given name 'Theme'.`

I entered it into my `style.xml` file exactly as given below. In the Sherlock library `/res/values/abs_themes.xml` file the style name matches mine exactly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, ABS uses (almost) the same API as the default ActionBar so just change the theme of the (duplicate) answer like this:

```
<style name="myStyle" parent="Theme.Sherlock">    
     <item name="android:selectableItemBackground">@android:drawable/item_background_holo_dark</item>
     <item name="selectableItemBackground">@android:drawable/item_background_holo_dark</item>
</style>
```

And the drawable:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:exitFadeDuration="@android:integer/config_mediumAnimTime">

<item android:drawable="@drawable/list_selector_disabled_holo_dark" android:state_enabled="false" android:state_focused="true" android:state_pressed="true"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/list_selector_disabled_holo_dark" android:state_enabled="false" android:state_focused="true"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/list_selector_background_transition_holo_dark" android:state_focused="true" android:state_pressed="true"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/list_selector_background_transition_holo_dark" android:state_focused="false" android:state_pressed="true"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/list_focused_holo" android:state_focused="true"/>
<item android:drawable="@color/transparent"/>

</selector>
```

You just inherit your styles from `Theme.Sherlock` and set an other `selectableItemBackground` attribute, but without the `android:` in front.

Comment: OK thanks, I've never dealt with a style file like this before though. Where does it go? I saw somewhere there should be a `res/styles/` directory but I do not have one. Is that because I'm in a lower API?

Comment: No. Just in res/values/ there you should have a styles.xml file.

Comment: Sorry, but I'm still not getting it to work. I've edited my question with more info and the error i'm getting if you have the time.

Comment: I've just come back to this project and have a small follow up question about this. I create the drawable file, and then I just call something along the lines of `actionBar.setBackgroundDrawable( drawable_file.xml )`?