# Change Color of Action Bar Title Android

Tags: android

I am writing an android app in which I am trying to change the color of the title of Action Bar by clicking on Button. As soon as, I click the button , the title gets hidden though I am passing the color code of YELLOW.
Here is my Code of MainActitvity.java

```
Button B;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    B = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    B.setOnClickListener(this);
}


public void onClick(View v) {
    android.app.ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
    Internal.setActionBarTitleColor(actionBar, 256);
}
```

Internal.java

```
  public static void setActionBarTitleColor(android.app.ActionBar actionBar, int titleColor) {
    if(actionBar == null)
        return;

    try {
        Field actionViewField = actionBar.getClass().getDeclaredField("mActionView");
        actionViewField.setAccessible(true);
        Object actionView = actionViewField.get(actionBar);
        if(actionView == null)
            return;

        Field titleTextField = actionView.getClass().getDeclaredField("mTitleView");
        titleTextField.setAccessible(true);
        TextView titleText = (TextView)titleTextField.get(actionView);

        if(titleText != null)
            titleText.setTextColor(titleColor);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: try to follow this tutorail it wil help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9019512/how-can-i-change-the-touch-effect-color-of-the-actionbar-in-android-3-0-and-high   https://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/styling.html

Answer (score 0):

```
actionBar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(0xff00DDED));
actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);  // required to force redraw
actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);
```

Comment: Its converting the whole Action Bar to Cyan color. And the title is still not displayed.

Answer (score 0):

```
    int titleId=Resources.getSystem().getIdentifier("action_bar_title", "id", "android");
    TextView yourTextView = (TextView)findViewById(titleId); 
    yourTextView.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
```

Answer (score 0):

The ActionBar title ID is hidden, or in other words, it's internal and accessing it can't be done typically. You can reference it using Resources.getIdentifier.

Follow the step below:

**1. Grab the ID for the action_bar_title**

```
int titleId = getResources().getIdentifier("action_bar_title", "id", "android");
```

**2. Now you can use the ID with a TextView**

```
TextView abTitle = (TextView) findViewById(titleId);
abTitle.setTextColor(colorId);
```

That's all.